# How to capture git error login in shell script

Tags: git, shell

i need to capture message from error login in git.

I have the following code section:

```
#!/bin/bash

...

git push origin master
```

Then the shell script ask me fot username and password:

> Username for github.com:
>
> Password for github.com:

So I insert a invalid username and passowrd. Then Git give me a error message:

> remote: Invalid username or password.
>
> fatal: Authentication failed for https://github.com/.../.../

How can i capture these error messages in a shell script to a variable?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works with me with '$?'

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': sld,sldk
Password for 'https://sld,sldk@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/KamelHacene/configeuh.git/'
$ echo $?
128
```

If the command has succeded, $? should return 0.
Just catch it in a variable (like 'var=$?') and you'll be good to go.

To catch the error message, just redirect your error output like this (stderr to file):

```
$ git push origin master 2>plop
Username for 'https://github.com': lskdls
Password for 'https://lskdls@github.com': 
$ cat plop
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/KamelHacene/configeuh.git/'
```

Or this (stderr to stdout. Use a variable to catch stdout) :

```
$ ploop=$(git push origin master 2>&1)
Username for 'https://github.com': skjdksd
Password for 'https://skjdksd@github.com': 
$ echo $ploop
remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/KamelHacene/configeuh.git/'
```

Comment: This is the line I needed: `ploop=$(git push origin master 2>&1)`.